# Weighted least squares with matrices as unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times N_t}, U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times N_t}$, with $ N_t \gg m,n$.
Moreover, $\epsilon = S - M U$, with $\epsilon$ zero mean white noise with covariance $C_e$.

How to estimate $M$ using a least squares and using the knowledge of $S,M, Ce$ ?
Is there a closed-form expression ?

Comment: I changed $N_t>>m,n$ to $N_t\gg m,n.$ This is coded as `N_t\gg m,n`.